# Is the meaning of **I'll keep an eye out for it** understood outside of the UK ?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, international

I sometime write in emails :

**I'll keep an eye out for it**

OR

**I'll keep an eye out for your email**

Im in the UK and i think that the majority on english speakers in the UK would understand this, but in other major english speaking countries would this be understood ?

Comment: French pal here, I've learned English through school and a variety of other sources (Internet, series, articles) and have no trouble understanding it. What makes you think some people would have a hard time understanding this expression? It seems quite common to me.

Comment: I'm an American. We use it too.

Comment: Canadian here, can confirm it is also used throughout the country.

Comment: Yeah, the term is [common in the US as well](http://bitsandpieces.us/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/imageskeeping-an-eye-out.jpg).

Comment: Commonly used in Australia too.

Comment: @MadWard the reason i wandered is that it doesn't actually make sense if you where to interpret it logically.

Comment: @sam most idioms don't logically make sense

Comment: @V0ight That is because sense doesn't logically make idioms. The great thing about them is that they do not need an explanation.

Comment: Never heard of it or seen it before. But I'll keep an eye out for it...